# Best way for allowing %d.%m.%Y-formated strings to be passed a model's DateField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-datetime

I have been trying to understand the effects of the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS settings and the way Django processes these datfields but whatever I find is either not understanable to me (being relatively new to DJango) or seems to relate to Forms, which doesn't seem to be applicable here.

My user model has a birthday field:

```
class LocalUser(AbstractUser):
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and I want to create users from a csv.
I upload the csv and process its contents:

```
class InputFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()

    def process_file(self):
        file = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['file'].file, encoding='utf-8-sig')
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=";")
        l = LocalUser(**dict(line))
        l.save()
```

The csv contains dates in e. g. "01.01.1999" format. It works when I reformat dates e. g. via `line["birthday"] = datetime.strptime(line["birthday"], '%d.%m.%Y')` but I am sure there must be a nicer solution, one where I don't have to modify code wherever a birthday is passed to the user model as string.

In the settingy.py file I added:

```
#USE_L10N = False
from django.conf.global_settings import DATE_INPUT_FORMATS
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%d.%m.%Y',)
```

but that doesn't help.

The error message I get is:

> ValidationError at /import_export/import_data
>
> ["'11.02.1993' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Do you have any recommendations on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` is related to the forms, so won't do the conversion while saving the model instance.

You can override the `save` method of the model and add the necessary conversion code there. It would also be better to handle all the patterns mentioned in `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` to keep a common source of truth:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class LocalUser(AbstractUser):
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.birthday is not None:
            if isinstance(self.birthday, str):
                for pattern in settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS:
                    try:
                        self.birthday = datetime.strptime(self.birthday, pattern)
                        break
                    except ValueError:
                        continue
                else:
                    raise ValidationError('Not a valid date string')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, if you have your pattern(s) added to `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` (like you do now), the automatic conversion would be taken place while saving.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great with a minor fix to your code: `self.birthday = datetime.strptime(pattern, self.birthday)` (first pattern, then value) ;)

Comment: @MaxMike No problem. But I have it exactly like that.

Comment: ah, darn, I made a mistake in my comment: I mean the other way round, it has to be first the string, then the pattern: `self.birthday = datetime.strptime(self.birthday, pattern)`